# Security issue with Facebook JS SDK

Tags: php, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using the facebook JS sdk to login a user. These are the steps that I follow:-

1) I use the `FB.login(...)` to get the details of the user.
2) Now, after receiving the details from Facebook, I send a POST request using jQuery's `$.post(..)` function to a php page say `FBUser.php` with the parameters - `name`,`uid`(Facebook User Id),`email` and `access_token` for `publish_actions`.
3) Now in the `FBUser.php` page, I do all the stuff like converting the short-lived-token to long-lived and then I check that if the `uid`  received is present in my `users` table. If it is not, I create a new user, else I log in the old user. 
Today, I just realized that I was making such a big security compromise because anyone can send a POST request to the `FBUser.php` page with a `uid` of an existing user and get access to his account. But, on the other hand I am sure that some big websites also use the JS SDK. So obviously, I am wrong somewhere. What would be the correct procedure to log in the user securely and preventing his account getting hacked?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.3#confirm

Comment: @CBroe , thanks for giving the link. Did not go to that section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should match the app and user id first, then you should check the access token, like this: 
`graph.facebook.com/debug_token?input_token={token-to-check}&access_token={app-token}`

You can get the app token from https://developers.facebook.com/tools/accesstoken/

Comment: I wanted to say that you coped the answer from @CBroe's comment but the link which you gave helped me So...+1

Answer (score 1):

You can get the uid of the user using the access token that was sent to you, by using this token to access Facebook graph and query "/me".
You shouldn't relay on the uid that is sent by the client. My application only receives the access token and gets the rest of the data from a server-to-server call.